# How to load CSV data with embedded double quote using CSV serde in Hive. Without updating the incoming data file

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I have text file like below :

```
1,"TEST"Data","SAMPLE DATA"
```

and the table structure is like this :

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1( id string, col1 string , col2 string )
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' 
  LOCATION 'mylocation/test1'`
```

When I am putting the file in concerned HDFS location. 2nd and 03 rd column are populating as `null` that is because of the double quote in between (TEST"Data).

One way is to update the data file using escape character "/" but we are not allowed to update the incoming data. How can I load data properly and escape these embedded double quotes.

Appreciate the help !!

Answer (score 2):

You can load it using **RegexSerDe**

#### Demo

**bash**

```
mkdir test1
```

---

```
cat>test1/file.txt
1,"TEST"Data","SAMPLE DATA"
2,"TEST Data","SAMPLE DATA"
3,"TEST","Data","SAMPLE","DATA"
```

---

```
hdfs dfs -put test1 /tmp
```

**hive**

```
create external table test1 
( 
    id      string
   ,col1    string
   ,col2    string 
)
    row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    with serdeproperties  
    (
        'input.regex' = '^(\\d+?),"(.*)","(.*)"$'
    )
    location '/tmp/test1'
;
```

---

```
select * from test1
;
```

---

```
+----------+----------------------+-------------+
| test1.id |      test1.col1      | test1.col2  |
+----------+----------------------+-------------+
| 1        | TEST"Data            | SAMPLE DATA |
| 2        | TEST Data            | SAMPLE DATA |
| 3        | TEST","Data","SAMPLE | DATA        |
+----------+----------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Are you still here?